# Get in wsgi.py apache virtualhost name

Tags: python, django, http-host

I have apache settings:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site1.ru
    ServerAlias site2.ru

    WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/wsgi.py
..
```

I want to load some host specific settings to django settings. So, how can i get HTTP_HOST (site1.ru or site2.ru) in django settings or in wsgi.py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
in wsgi.py

import os, sys
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] ='project.settings'
```

Comment: i know this. But in wsgi.py want to set os.environ['HOST'] and then read it in settings

Comment: you have to define a middleware function like handler using HttpRequest.get_host() to be able to get it settings.

Answer (score 0):

[`request.META['HTTP_HOST']`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META), same as all the other headers.

Comment: How can i get request in wsgi.py? or settings?

Comment: You can't get it in the settings because it only exists as part of the request. Look in `environ` in the WSGI handler.